# @Scheduled works in Spring Boot application but not in @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, junit

What is the reason that the `@Scheduled` function runs in Spring Boot Application but not in test environment (`@SpringBootTest`) ?

I am following the tutorial at https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-scheduling-tasks, the repository's test runs fine, but mine `@Scheduled` function does not run for once in my test, although it is working fine in my Spring Boot application.

Is it because of the version of Junit (The tutorial is using Junit5 while I am using JUnit 4) ?

My purpose of this test is to check the correctness of the configuration of my scheduler.

Below is the code I replicated with difference in Junit version.

*BootApplication.java*

```
package com.itsedo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

// SecurityAutoConfiguration: exclude default spring security boot file.
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("com.itsedo")
@EnableScheduling
public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BootApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*ScheduledTasks.java*

```
package com.itsedo.scheduler;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

File `ScheduledTasksTest.java`

```java
package com.itsedo.test;

import org.awaitility.Duration;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.awaitility.Awaitility.await;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeast;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import com.itsedo.scheduler.ScheduledTasks;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ScheduledTasksTest {

    @SpyBean
    ScheduledTasks tasks;

    @Test
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        await().atMost(Duration.TEN_SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
            verify(tasks, atLeast(2)).reportCurrentTime();
        });
    }
}
```

*Test Output*
[image: Test Output]

*Running Spring Boot application*

[image: Running Spring Boot Application]

Comment: I suspect the fact that you created an `@SpyBean`. This creates a proxy of the class which probably makes the `@Scheduled` annotation invisible and hence not scheduling tasks. Try to run it without the `@SpyBean` and see if it runs then.

Comment: But the https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-scheduling-tasks/blob/main/complete/src/test/java/com/example/schedulingtasks/ScheduledTasksTest.java also use `@SpyBean`.

Comment: With JUnit 5 and thus a recent spring Boot and Mockito version. The fact that you use JUnit4 (why actually) makes me think you use older versions and thus not following the tutorial.

Comment: Because I am adding feature to the existing application, so I try to test it with simpler approach instead of the actual function.

Comment: Please show us the Application class, and the package names for service and application.

Comment: You import `import com.ScheduledTasks;` but your code is in a different package. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes. Btw, I can confirm the cause lies in the version of `JUnit`. After I changed the `spring-boot-starter-parent` of the tutorial repo to the same as mine and also the version of `JUnit` from 5 to 4, the test failed too.